# проблема с размером документа в meteor js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, meteor

Для своего небольшого приложения на meteor.js я хочу сделать бесконечную прокрутку. Я воспользовался примером реализации из статьи https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-21-pagination-system-with-infinite-scroll/43
Эта реализация опирается на отлавливание события `scroll`.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
      incrementLimit();
    }
});
```

В процессе скроллинга сравниваются значения прокрученной области + размера окна и размера документа. Когда неравенство верно, подгружаются новые данные.
Однако, мне не нравится, что при отсутствии полосы прокрутки алгоритм не срабатывает. Такое возможно, например, если начальная порция данных мала и умещается на экране. Я решил сделать проверку, и в случае проблемы подгружать данные до появления полосы прокрутки.

Однако, я столкнулся с проблемой.
Ниже часть моего кода:

```
Template.content_table_tmpl.rendered = function () {
    // is triggered every time we scroll
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 10) {
            incrementLimit();
        }
    });

    if (($(window).height() >= $(document).height())){
        console.log($(window).height() , $(document).height());
        incrementLimit();
    }
    if (($(window).height() >= $(document).height())){
        console.log($(window).height() , $(document).height());
        incrementLimit();
    }
}
```

Я ожидаю увидеть следующий результат:
Если размеры окна больше или равны размерам документа, то подгружается новая порция данных, размеры документа увеличиваются, после чего снова происходит такая же проверка. Естественно, не конечный код, а только рабочий момент отладки.

Сама проблема в том, что в процессе выполнения в консоль оба раза выводятся одни и те же значения. Второй `if` выполняется, даже если после первого появляется полоса прокрутки.
В браузере из консоли `$(document).height()` дает уже другое, более верное значение.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второе выполняется так же как первое, потому что оно выполняется ПРЯМО СРАЗУ, то есть оно не ждет, когда сработает первый `incrementLimit()`. Можете проверить это обернув второй кусок `setTimeout()`.

И что будет, если сделать вот так? По идее сразу отработает как надо при загрузке страницы:

```
Template.content_table_tmpl.rendered = function () {
    // is triggered every time we scroll
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 10) {
            incrementLimit();
        }
    }).scroll();
}
```

Так оно отработает один раз. + внутри `incrementLimit()` ПОСЛЕ загрузки новой порции проверять еще раз, если необходимо.

Comment: Воспользовался вашим советом и все заработало как часы. Благодарю за ответ!